# What is COM+? What is equivalent for COM+ in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

What is COM+? What is equivalent for COM+ in .Net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

COM+ was Microsoft's offering in the battle for the middle tier that raged in the late nineties.  A set of extensions built on top of COM with typical middleware duties like componentizing modules across machines and getting them to work together in a transaction-safe way.  CORBA was another one, now also largely forgotten.

The only thing it really accomplished was to make Java a significant force.

Answer (score 3):

ServicedComponent http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c05y13x(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right here on wikipedia. Has a section on .Net
[Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)

There is no equivalent in .Net as you can still use COM+ in .Net but there are better ways of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "better ways"?  I'm trying as best as I can to avoid learning COM, as I have been enveloped in C# for the past 18 months.

Comment: @Larry Have you looked at WCF / soap services in .Net or using an enterprise service bus?

Answer (score 0):

[COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz%28VS.71%29.aspx) used to be a rather dangerous, if not overly-hyped feature.

Why dangerous? It used to collect and dispose of live com pointers, thus pulling the rug right out from under you. Oh my, it was so much fun. It could be fixed by now I would hope.